# Unix : run 2 commands which take input from a pipe?

Tags: unix, pipe

Updated : 
Thanks for your answers. As I said, my q was just a translation of my usecase. 
Let me get into more details of what I want to achieve. 
In my dev env, we use "ade" as our version control system what I want to do is :

```
ade describetrans | awk '/myapps/{ print $2 }' | sort -fr | xargs -iF ade unbranch F
```

Now, every single time I run the unbranch command, a new file/dir gets checked out. so I need to run ade checkin -all after all my unbranch commands. So I needed something like

```
"pre part till sort" | xargs -iF (ade unbranch + ade checkin -all)
```

Any way to run 2 commands on the op of pipe ?

Thanks

Original question asked :

I can translate the usecase I have into the following :

I need to get the 1st line of a file. I do

```
cat file | head -1
```

Now I want to do this on a list of files. How do I do the following in one unix command ??
Eg :

```
find . -name "*.log" | ( xargs -iF cat F  | head -1 )
```

Obviously the brackets in the above command do not work.

is there a way to pipe the output of the find command and do 2 commands on it ( cat and head ) ? Tried using ; and && but dint help.
I can create a script - but wanted to do this in one command.

Again - this is just a translation of the case I have.

thanks
Rohan

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for serverfault.com?  Or is this considered shell programming?  :-)

Comment: It's a borderline case. A complex shell command typed in interactive mode is not programming and belongs on superuser.com, but writing a shell script containing the very same line is programming. Should be discussed on Meta.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `head` accepts more than one file name, so you can simply write:

```
 head -q -n 1 *.log
```

or:

```
find . -name '*.log' -exec head -n 1 '{}' ';'
```

However, if you **really** need to duplicate the stream, then use `tee` and do something along the lines of:

```
 wget -O - http://example.com/dvd.iso | tee >(sha1sum > dvd.sha1) > dvd.iso
```

This example is taken from `info coreutils 'tee invocation'`.

---

**UPDATE** (Following the `ade` comment) In your case `tee` will not work.  You need to perform a task after another task finishes, and `tee` will trigger the tasks more or less simultaneously (modulo buffering).

Another approach will work, **provided that there are no spaces in the input lines** (a serious issue, I know, but I'm not sure how to overcome it right now).  I'll start with a generic solution:

```
echo -e 'Foo\nBar\nBaz' | ( for i in `cat` ; do echo 1$i ; echo 2$i ; done )
```

Here, `echo -e 'Foo\nBar\nBaz'` creates a sample multi-line input, `echo 1$i` is the first command to run, `echo 2$i` is the second command to run.

I'm not familiar with `ade` and I don't have it installed on my system, but I'm guessing that in your case something like this might work:

```
ade describetrans | awk '/myapps/{ print $2 }' | sort -fr | ( for i in `cat` ; do ade unbranch $i ; ade checkin -all $i ; done )
```

Comment: This is fine, but you might replace the `;` with a (nonstandard) `+` to have `find` pass multiple names to one single `head` subprocess.

Comment: @Philipp Oh, I didn't know about the `+`, it's very cool!  Instead of altering my answer (again), I've upvoted your informative comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. As I said, my q was just a translation of my usecase. 

Let me get into more details of what I want to achieve. 
In my dev env, we use "ade" as our version control system

what I want to do is : 
ade describetrans | awk '/myapps/{ print $2 }' | sort -fr | xargs -iF ade unbranch F 

Now, every single time I run the unbranch command, a new file/dir gets checked out. so I need to run ade checkin -all after all my unbranch commands. 
So I needed something like 
<pre part till sort> | xargs -iF (ade unbranch + ade checkin -all) 
Any way to run 2 commands on the op of pipe ?

Answer (score 1):

Useless use of `cat`. Simply pass the file names to `head`:

```
find . -name '*.log' -exec head -n 1 '{}' '+'
```

or

```
find . -name '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 head -n 1
```

**EDIT:** This will print headers for each file. On Linux, this can be suppressed with `-q`, but on other systems you must make sure that `head` is called with a single argument:

```
find . -name '*.log' -exec head -n 1 '{}' ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be, by piping input into `head` rather than simply giving it a filename(s):

```
head -n1 `find -X . -name '*.log' | xargs`
```

If you don't need to traverse subdirectories, you can make it even simpler:

```
head -n1 *.log
```

You can screen out the filename headers by piping through grep: `| grep -v '^(==> .* <==)?$' | grep -v '^$'`

Comment: The first one won't work if a file name contains a space or newline.

Comment: And the second one will additionally print headers with file names, unless you add `-q`.

Comment: `-q` is nonstandard and doesn't exist on BSD systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ade describetrans | awk '/myapps/{ print $2 }' | sort -fr | xargs sh -c 'ade unbranch "$@"; ade checkin -all "$@"' arg0
```

This is assuming that `ade` accepts multiple files at once and `ade checkin -all` needs to be called for every file.

The string `arg0` supplies the value of `$0` in the `-c` string.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know `ade`, so I will have to guess what the 2 commands want
to run really are. But if you have GNU Parallel
http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed one of these should
work:

```
ade describetrans | awk '/myapps/{ print $2 }' | sort -fr |
parallel -j1 ade unbranch {} ";" ade checkin -all {}

ade describetrans | awk '/myapps/{ print $2 }' | sort -fr |
parallel -j1 ade unbranch {} ";" ade checkin -all

ade describetrans | awk '/myapps/{ print $2 }' | sort -fr |
parallel -j1 ade unbranch {} ; ade checkin -all
```

If `ade` can be run in parallel, you can remove `-j1`.

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ